# How to disable key events on parent while typing on an input field?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a browser game and i have keys set which moves the player around.
Let's get a weird example to help understand the problem.

Space bar - Jump

So when i go to the chatbox, and start typing the player jumps every time you press the space bar like it is intended to. However, when i am typing in a input field, it should not jump the player for pressing the space bar.

This is the input field:

```
<textarea id="chatfield1" class="pull-left" placeholder="Participate in coversation"></textarea>
```

I have a keymanager that enables and disables the ability to execute functions with keys.

```
keymanager.suspend();
keymanager.resume();
```

How could i do this?

edit:
My keymanager works like this:

```
var keymanager = {
                  "active": true,
                  "suspend": () => {
                    keymanager.active = false;
                  },
                  "resume": () => {
                    keymanager.active = true;
                  }
                };
                document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
                    if (!keymanager.active)
                    {
                        return; // do not process any keys
                    }
```

Comment: Maybe using two listeners on the `textarea`, one for the `onfocus` then call `keymanager.suspend()` and another to the `onblur` event, calling `keymanager.resume()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the event [*bubbles*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616704/1814486) from child-to-parent.

`document.body` is the parent to almost every element on your page, including your input/textarea.

You have (at least) 2 options:

- Listen for the `keyup` on a non-parent element of your input/textarea. For example, if this is an HTML5 canvas game you should probably listen for game-related key events on the `<canvas>` itself.
- Stop the `keyup` event propagation when you type in the input/textarea.

Here's the second example in action:

```js
document.querySelector('#parent').addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  // this shouldn't run since we stop the event propagation below.
  console.log('keyup detected on parent')
})

document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  console.log('keyup detected on input')
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <input id="input" placeholder="Type here..." value=""/>
</div>
```

That being said, you should probably go for the 1st option instead. Explicitly stopping event propagation every time some secondary input is required will soon become unwieldy.